# Using Terraform, how can I add multiple search domains to /etc/resolve.conf to an AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: linux, dns, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

in my AWS ec2 linux instance I need my /etc/resolve.conf file to look something like

```
search my.domain my.other.domain
nameserver 10.10.10.10
```

my terraform object looks like

```
resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options" "dns_option" {
    domain_name = "${var.environment}.my.domain"
    domain_name_servers = ["${split(",", var.vpc_dns_server)}"]
}
```

I need to add multiple domain_name objects I think?

Comment: This question could really do with  'hashicorp' and 'terraform' tags but I don't have the reputation to add them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Add the aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association to your code:

   > `resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options_association" "vpc_dhcp_association" {
   >   vpc_id = "vpc-abcdefab"
   >   dhcp_options_id = "${aws_vpc_dhcp_options.dns_option.id}"
   >   }`

   - For your VPC ID you can reference it with something like
     `${aws_vpc.myvpc.id}`
2. To have multiple domains on your resolv.conf file you need to put multiple domain names separated by `space` like this:

   > `resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options" "dns_option" {
   >   domain_name = "${var.environment1}.my.domain ${var.environment2}.my.other.domain"
   >   }`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify multiple search domains due to an AWS limitation.

[AWS DHCP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html) `domain_name` value is (correctly) sent to the client as [DHCP Option 15](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2132#section-3.17), which only supports a single domain name (no spaces).

[DHCP Option 119](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3397#section-2) is required to support a `domain search` list, *but the AWS DHCP implementation has no support*.